# Assignments Python List

Tags: list, variable-assignment

If I have a list like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I delete the first element:

```
del(a[0])
```

How many assignments occurs? Does one assignment only occur when your e.g. set a[1] = 7? Or can you say that 4 assignments occur in the background
since every element in the list gets a new index?

Comment: Do not name python lists `list`, as it overrides a builtin name.

Comment: Deleting elements is an O(n) average case operation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think it's worth editing your question again, but for future reference - we put the language in the tags (and generally avoid putting the language in the title) : https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging